# ASP.NET v4 Input string was not in a correct format exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a website in production (ASP.NET v4), where on the login page we are occasionally catching the exception 'Input string was not in a correct format'.
This is being caught within Application_Error which logs its details

The exception is taken from `Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException()`. However, the stack trace is only reported as the following:

> Stack Trace:
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value)

The web page doesn't have any need to try and convert input (as it only takes a username), nor does it seem to call any VB functions which do.

How can I track down this intermittent error?

Comment: To me this looks like you're catching a typo with it, where someone intends to press e.g. the 'e' key but actualy hits '4'. And this as the first character of the login, causing VB to assume a number and hence the (failed) conversion attempt.

Comment: Hi, there's no validation against the input for the username. The username can be any numeric or alphabetic

Comment: Don't do `GetBaseException()`. Get the full exception. Then provide all those details in your question.

Comment: asp.net has some built in systems to prevent "bad" input. So if a user types in this <script>alert('hello');</script> then when  you re-display the page, that text will actually start to be interpreted by the browser as CODE ENTERED by the user! So, some types of input will cause a error - as this protection is built into asp.net web pages for you.  It is simply a trappable error on that page.